# HTML form - only works on a single button in a loop

Tags: html, forms, flask

So I am creating a table with a form and I have 2 rows the problem is the submit button works only on one button and the second submit it does the form but doesn't send any values [image: only works on 1 button]

```
   <tr>
        {% for(username, computer_mac, assign_value) in zip(users_username, computers_mac, assigned_values) %}
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <td>
                computer number: 
                <select class="custom-select" name={{username}}>
                {% for client_id in  computer_client_id%}
                <option value={{client_id}} name={{client_id}} >{{client_id}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
                <option value="-1" name="-1">None</option>
                <option hidden selected>{{assign_value}}</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td>{{username}} ({{computer_mac}})</td>
                <td class="assigned_values">{{assign_value}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md a" id="button-id" value="submit">
                </td>   
                <td>
                    <div id="status"></div>
                </td>
            </form>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
```

---

```
{{username}} = Raz
{{client_id}} = 1
{{other_username}} = a
{{other_client_id}} = None
```

in the first button, I can see that it [image: sends] `"{{username}}={{client_id}}&{{other_username}}={{other_client_id}}"` what I'd like to have is for every button it'd be separate so the first button will have his `{{username}}={{client_id}}` and the second button would have his {{other_username}}={{other_client_id}} how do I do it?

JS data send:

```
var data = $("form").serialize();
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'admin/data',
                data: data,
```

Comment: @user3783243 one above the for loop

Comment: @user3783243 I tried getting the <tr> out of the for loop and it just puts both of the rows in the same row, what do you mean by "the resulting HTML"? and why would you need javascript it's just how the form sends the data

Comment: @user3783243 Note: putting the form and tr outside of the loop is resulting by the first button to return Raz=1 as I want but the second button doesn't work what it should do is a=None

Comment: @user3783243 added the important thing in how I send the data

Comment: @user3783243 I solved the problem

Comment: @user3783243 Kinda what my code did now is that it did work for every button(by making a class to the button it was an ID before that's why it was only on the first one) but I still had the `Raz=1&a=None` for both so I found the bottom index by using the `$(this) and indexOf`, split the `Raz=1&a=None` in `&` and took the position of the resulting of the `$(this) and indexOf`

Comment: @user3783243 Yeah you are right. I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved it the first problem was that I needed to create a class for the button so it will work on multiple buttons instead of 1:
so simply adding to the button class: `"button-class"` and delete the id
now the problem is that for both of the buttons the form output is this `Raz=1&a=None` which could be good for you but I wanted them separate so 
button 1 -  `Raz=1`
button 2 - `a=None`
so what I did is that I found the index of the button that I am clicking on
`var currentIndex = $('.button-class').index(this);`
and simply split at `&`

```
try{
                data = data.split('&');
                data = data[currentIndex]
            }
            catch(err){
                data = ""
            }
```

and that's it now I have the right info for the different buttons.